Horror movie with house haunting father who goes crazy when he's close to the house
I remember seeing a movie (English movie, most likely American) about a decade ago where there's a family who move into a house, and the family (which consists of I think a mother, father and a daughter and son) notice that the dad is acting strange. As the movie progresses the audience notices that when the dad is close to the house he becomes crazy. For example there's one scene where the dad is chopping wood in the yard and asks the son to hold the wood whilst he's chopping it, the father becomes very aggressive shouting at the son. I remember the final act being the family successfully getting the dad away from the house, and one of the final shots being the father waking up on a boat with the family sailing away from the house. 

The Amityville Horror remake with Ryan Reynolds had a wood chopping scene like that, but I haven't seen the whole movie so I can't be sure about this answer.
